# Regex accepting characters that shouldn't

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9-_ãÃñÑéÉêÊúÚíÍáÁõÕàÀèÈìÌòÒùÙçü.#()+=%$&?¿@!\s]+$/
```

For some reason, the "é" character lets pass the "©" character pass.
What's wrong?

Comment: what character set is your code saved in?

Comment: I'm using UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 characters are multibyte. The expression was doing a literal interpretation of the character, in this case, "é" equals "Ã ©". For a accurate interpretation, use "(*UTF8)":

```
/(*UTF8)^[A-Za-z0-9-_ãÃñÑéÉêÊúÚíÍáÁõÕàÀèÈìÌòÒùÙçü.#()+=%$&?¿@!\s]+$/
```

I found the answer here: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php#95828

Answer (score 1):

You can more simply add the `u` pattern modifier to the end of your pattern with the same effect.  Additionally, I'll suggest that you condense your pattern with `\w` which represents *any letter, digit or underscore. Equivalent to **[a-zA-Z0-9***]_

Suggested Pattern: `~^[-\wãÃñÑéÉêÊúÚíÍáÁõÕàÀèÈìÌòÒùÙçü.#()+=%$&?¿@!\s]+$~u`

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aC3TY))

```
$in = "AZ a-z\t0-9-_ãÃñÑéÉêÊúÚíÍáÁõÕàÀèÈìÌòÒùÙçü\r\n.#()+=%$&?¿@!©";  // string contains ©
echo preg_match('~^[A-Za-z0-9-_ãÃñÑéÉêÊúÚíÍáÁõÕàÀèÈìÌòÒùÙçü.#()+=%$&?¿@!\s]+$~', $in, $out) ? $out[0] : 'fail';

echo "\n\nNow with a unicode flag...\n";
echo preg_match('~^[-\wãÃñÑéÉêÊúÚíÍáÁõÕàÀèÈìÌòÒùÙçü.#()+=%$&?¿@!\s]+$~u', $in, $out) ? $out[0] : 'fail';
//  this is shorter--^^                            here is the magic--^
```

Output:  (The first pattern doesn't not fail on `©` as intented, the second pattern does.)

```
AZ a-z  0-9-_ãÃñÑéÉêÊúÚíÍáÁõÕàÀèÈìÌòÒùÙçü
.#()+=%$&?¿@!©

Now with a unicode flag...
fail
```

Comment: Great suggestion. Thank you!